# SHA1 warning for TLS server when I have not selected it

Tags: java, ssl, bouncycastle

I am getting a warning from the a line of code responsible for setting up an SSLContext instance:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS", "BCJSSE");
```

The line of code exists in both my SSLServer and client implementations, as of yet I am not sure what it is even complaining about but I have tried different tls versions with no success.

this is the warning:

```
Jul 02, 2020 3:17:04 PM org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.PropertyUtils getStringSecurityProperty
INFO: Found string security property [jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms]: SSLv3, RC4, DES, 
MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL
Jul 02, 2020 3:17:04 PM org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.PropertyUtils getStringSecurityProperty
INFO: Found string security property [jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms]: MD2, MD5, SHA1 jdkCA & usage TLSServer,
RSA keySize < 1024, DSA keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224
Jul 02, 2020 3:17:04 PM org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints create
WARNING: Ignoring unsupported entry in 'jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms': SHA1 jdkCA & usage 
TLSServer
```

Comment: That looks like a warning about the contents of the disabled algorithms list, not a warning about anything you're doing. Maybe you're missing a comma after "SHA1"?

Comment: This is  verbatim so I don't think I am missing anything. What is it warning of then? java.com says its a constraint on having SHA1 in certificate chains which is what made me think that.

Comment: You need to check all certificages in the chain, up to the trusted one, not just the leaf one.

Comment: It's a V1 certificate (trust anchor) there's only the one. What exactly would I be checking it for?

Comment: What does "Ignoring unsupported entry in 'jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms'" mean to you? Where is there any reference at all to any certificate?

Comment: As I said I thought it was a certificate problem because on searching the warning there was mention of it being related to barring SHA1 in certificates for security reasons however I have since found the line which generates this warning to be this "            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS", "BCJSSE");" which of course has nothing to do with certificates so I am trying to figure why.

Comment: "Why" is very simple. The bouncycastle jsse provider does not recognize the new constraints from JEP 288, namely "SHA1 jdkCA & usage TLSServer". It is ignoring it, and so won't do any checking implied by it.

Comment: Ok sure well would that have any effect on the connection. My program hangs when I try to flush the following object                                                                                `try (ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(cSock.getOutputStream()))) {
               output.writeObject(new Test(23));                                            
               output.flush();`